Optimal Hedging Frequency using Black-Scholes and GBM (simplyfied)
I am trying to derive an optimal hedging interval for a delta-replicated European call option from the Black-Scholes model.
To do that, I would like to compare the resulting hedging error with my trading costs.
I am currently hedging (i.e. adjusting the delta of) the position every day and am trying to find out whether more frequent intraday hedging makes sense.
Unfortunately, I am making a mistake in my assumptions somewhere which I am hoping you can point out.
What I tried so far:
Lets assume volatility and time to maturity stay the same and risk-free-rate = dividends = 0.
I'll also use $\Delta \delta \approx \gamma \cdot \Delta S$ to describe the change in Delta for a small change in price.
I can roughly calculate the hedging error for a small price change using a Taylor expansion of the option price.
$C(S) \approx C(S_0) + \delta(S_0) \cdot (S - S_0) + \frac{\gamma(S_0)}{2} \cdot (S - S_0)^2+...
$
Since I hold $\delta(S_0)$ in my portfolio, the error for a small change in price is roughly $\frac{1}{2} \gamma (\Delta S)^²$
Additionally, I can calculate the trading costs as:
$c \cdot \left| (\delta_t - \delta_0) \cdot S_{t} \right| \approx c \cdot \left| \gamma \cdot \Delta S \cdot (S_0 + \Delta S) \right|$
c is a constant representing my trading costs per trading volume.
Now, using geometric brownian motion $dS_t = \mu S_t \, dt + \sigma S_t \, dW_t$, I find the expected value for my hedging error and trading costs.
$\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{2} \gamma (\Delta S)^²] \approx \frac{1}{2} \gamma S^2 \sigma^2 \Delta t$
$\mathbb{E}[c \left| \gamma \Delta S (S_0 + \Delta S) \right|] \approx c \gamma S^2 \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$
This seems to be correct in my simulations.
However, when I try to calculate the total costs over a greater timespan T (one day for example), the hedging error seems to be the same no matter the hedging frequency.
Let $n = \frac{T}{\Delta t}$ the number of intervals/hedges, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2} \gamma S^2 \sigma^2 \Delta t = n \cdot \frac{1}{2} \gamma S^2 \sigma^2 \Delta t = \frac{1}{2} \gamma S^2 \sigma^2 T$
Adding this error to my costs (which decrease by increasing $\Delta t$) doesn't make much sense. Are my calculations wrong or my assumptions too simple? Do I have to calculate it completely differently? What am I doing wrong?
Please only use Black-Scholes and GBM in your answer and please also try to simplify it as much as possible. Thank you very much!

It  is totally counter-intuitive that (neglecting costs) the hedging error over $T$ should not depend on the trading interval $\Delta t,.$ The authors of this write up produce a number of graphs that show what we expect: hedging errors go down when we increase the number of trading dates.

Hi, thanks for your comment and the paper. Yes, Figure 3 shows the decrease of the expected hedging error when n is increased. However, this is just the expected error for one interval. I am trying to calculate the total error over T.

I do not think so. They present four Figures all showing the same error decrease. On p. 14 they mention that Figure 1 is for an option maturity of $T=1$ and for number of trading days in that interval (denoted by $N$) ranging from one to 65.

Think the intuitive logic is that hedging error will decrease with 1/sqrt(N) but costs increase with N where N is number of hedges over option life. So sharpe ratio will likely be some negative parabola.

I think the best solution would be to run monte carlo sims of real numbers. It sorts the academic theoretical chaff from the real word wheat.

In 2 standard texts Hull Derivatives and Wilmott introduction to quant finance they have template spreadsheets for monte carlo simulation of option stock hedging, you could modify to suit needs or rewrite in python,R, or Julia.

Assuming proportional transaction costs (to the size of the trade):
The number of shares, N, to be hedged at each interval is given by $$ N = \Delta(S_t + dS, t + dt) - \Delta(S_t, t) \approx \Gamma_t * dS$$ which expands to: $$ N \approx \Gamma * \sigma * S * dW $$
The incremental cost is given by the number shares, N, multiplied by the share price, multiplied by the transaction cost fraction, $\alpha$: $$ Cost = |N*S| * \alpha $$ $$ Cost = |\Gamma * \sigma * S^2 * dW| * \alpha $$
$|dW| > 0$, so costs are, obviously, non-zero. Rewriting $dW$ as $z\sqrt{dt}$, we can see that for an option with a $\frac{T}{dt}$ number of hedges over the life, T, total costs will scale with $\frac{T}{dt} * \sqrt{dt} = \frac{T}{\sqrt{dt}}$. So as the hedging interval moves to 0, costs move to infinity.
The expected return of a hedged short option position is given by: $$\frac{\Gamma S^2}{2} * (\sigma^2_i - \sigma^2_r) * dt$$ and the volatility is given by: $$ \frac{\Gamma S^2 \sigma^2_r}{2} * \sqrt{\frac{\kappa -1}{N}} $$ where $\kappa$ is the raw kurtosis, under GBM $\kappa = 2$.
The expected return drag from increasing the hedging frequency is approximately: $$\Gamma * S^2 * \sigma_r \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi * dt}}$$
Creating a Sharpe ratio gives: $$ \sqrt{\frac{N}{\kappa -1}} * (((\frac{\sigma^i}{\sigma_r})^2 -1) - \frac{\alpha\sqrt{\frac{8}{\pi}}}{\sigma_r * dt^\frac{3}{2}} )$$
You can then differentiate and maximise the sharpe ratio w.r.t hedging frequency.

A joke is cited in Sigmund Freud's Der Witz und seine Beziehung zum Unbewußten: "I take a bath every , whether I need it or not".  Whilst this math is very pretty, I think there's something fundamentally wrong with the notion of re-hedging at any fixed cadence whether the book needs it or not. Re-hedge when some factor sensitivity or VaR or P&L under stress scenarios is too much. Set small limits if you don't want P&L from gammas. BAU re-hedge during business hours, emergency re-hedge overnight or on weekends/holidays if needed.
